# Suggestion to optimize Impala data loading from Python

Tags: python, bulkinsert, impala

I created this code to upload data into a Table in **Impala** from `Python` but it's too slow.
I basically transformed a table into an array in order to avoid some errors that I was retrieving.

```
arr2 = np.array(tbl2)
```

`tbl2` has the following columns:

```
cols1 = ['DATE1', 'DATE2', 'REGION', 'STATE', 'CITY', 'N_SAMPLE', 'UOM', 'AVG_RESALE', 'STD_RESALE',
         'P_MIN_RESALE', 'P_MAX_RESALE', 'MARGEM_RESALE', 'COEF_RESALE', 'AVG_DISTRI', 'STD_DISTRI', 'P_MIN_DISTRI',
         'P_MAX_DISTRI', 'COEF_DISTRI', 'MATERIAL']
```

Then, the code to insert data:

```
sql_insert = f"INSERT INTO prd_product_123.table ({', '.join(cols1)}) VALUES ({', '.join(list('?'*len(cols1)))}) ;"

for i in range(0, len(arr2)):
    cursor.execute(sql_insert, list(arr2[i].transpose()))
    cursor.commit()
    print('Row ' + str(i) + ' loaded!')
```

The problem is the original table `tbl2` has over 1,000,000 rows, and by the way above, it would take days to load it into Impala.

Is there a way to load it more efficiently?

Comment: I guess typical way would be ETL-like: 1) load file into HDFS "as-is"; 2) optionally, define Impala/Hive table backed by this file; and 3) execute transformations and store the results into final table. This way, transform and load can get a degree of parallelism necessary to complete them in reasonable time.

Comment: Sorry for ignorance, but to load the file should I use the Impala shell?

Comment: I was thinking something like `$ hdfs dfs -put <local-file> <hdfs-location>`, not via Impala.

Comment: If I type this command on PowerShell it retrieves an error. I am on Windows machine...
Do you use an especific shell/cli or program to run it?

Comment: Yes, it is part of Hadoop CLI. Hadoop needs to be installed and configured on your machine.

Comment: Got it. So, even if I want to connect with (Cloudera) Hue-Impala, I need to connect in machine....Let's see.